# Laravel unit test not saving to database

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to test some things in laravel but I cant even get past the most basic part.

I want to get the results from the database. Do some things. Add them back to another table and then asset that they exist in the new table and are correctly altered.

However, it is not storing to my database. This is what I have so far

```
public function getUser($id) 
    {
        return DB::raw("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id");
    }


public function testGetUsers()
    {

        $users = [97];

        foreach($users as $key => $value) {
            $response = $this->getUser($key);

            DB::raw("INSERT INTO user_tested (user_id, response) VALUES ($key, $response)");
        }
        
       
    }
```

When I run the artisan command in the terminal I only get the warning:

> get users → This test did not perform any assertions  /tests/Unit/testUsers.php:17

Which I expect because there were no assertions. However the code should still have run, no? Nothing is saved in the database.

also, if someone can tell me how to log out to the terminal whilst doing this that would be really helpful in debugging.

Comment: And what u want to test with this? It's not a test.

Comment: The test part hasnt happened yet. It broke as I was building the test.

Comment: If you want to prepare env for test - override setUp() function and make al actions after calling parent::setUp()

Comment: @Maksim I do not know how to do this. Could you provide a working answer ?

Comment: This is not freelance site :) check phpunit docs and, for example, Laravel tests. People here cannot teach you how do write tests - only help with concrete problem.

Comment: @Maksim no but it is a helpful site and you suggested something that is half-complete. The reason there is an answer button is for people to help and answer a complete solution. Its not using it as a freelance site for asking someone to extend their answer. If you dont want top help dont respond at all.

Comment: @JamesG are you using `use RefreshDatabase;` trait ? Also, I recommend 100% to use `models` instead of raw DB in Tests... it makes no sense to use them in tests as you want to test code, not queries in the test itself. Can you explain more as we cannot help you with what you have now ? Add more info please

Comment: I agree, check phpunit.xml and verify that you're actually using a database connection in tests as well. You may be using an in-memory database connection, you may be resetting the database before or after tests. The error your reporting indicates it ran successfully. You just don't know where it stored the values.

Comment: You can echo output from tests. Run phpunit in verbose mode.